# Corrigendum for wrong reporting of results

Tags: writing, errors-erratum

My paper got published in a good journal but later I noticed that in the final results table I have mistakenly written the parameters used in the previous literatures and not what I have calculated for one of the ions. I know it's a terrible mistake to do. I can't figure out how to write the corrigendum.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Write a letter to the editor, stating that in your paper so-and-so, table 5.7 should be replaced by [insert corrected table]. Use the format for the journal, so they can publish it as a corrigendum in the next issue. Perhaps add also a corrected version of the paper, to be archived instead of the erroneous one.

Comment: Make sure the corrigendum explicitly says what part of the paper's conclusions need to be changed, or that the change does not affect any conclusions.  If the problem was simply that the wrong number was published, but not used in any calculations etc, it's not a big deal.  If the wrong number was used to reach conclusions, it's important to spell out what needs to be re-interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Following [The 5th Korean Council of Science Editors'Workshop (2012)](http://blog.bcrec.web.id/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/5%C8%B8_12-HandoutHow-to-write-errata-corrigendum-and-retraction-Jocelyn-Graf.pdf), I copy and paste here for further reference:

> **What Should an Erratum Include?**
>
> - The complete bibliographic information for the corrected article
> - An explanation of the error and the correction of the error
>
> **What Should a Corrigendum Include?**
>
> - The complete bibliographic information for the corrected article
> - Acknowledgement of the person who helped find the error(s)
> - Explanation of the correction, whether brief or extensive
> - Brief errors can be mentioned along with the corrected form
> - In the correction of an entire figure or table, only the erroneous parts
>     need to be listed, along with a complete revised figure or table
> - Citation of any articles related to the correction, along with a
>     standard reference list